# How to cope with different return types of a Clojure function when called by Java?

Tags: java, clojure, interop

I want to call the `binomial` Clojure function from Java. One problem I encounter is that it returns different data types, either `long` (e. g., n=5, k=3) or `BigInt` (e. g., n=20, k=10). On Java side, it should be a BigInteger.

There are at least two options to overcome this, which is preferable?

1. Force Clojure function to return BigInt (I don't know if this is possible. I tried type hints, but it still returns either `long` or `BigInt`).
2. In Java, use Pattern match on return value and check type, then convert appropriate.

**Clojure**

```
(ns sample.hello
  (:import (clojure.lang BigInt)))

(defn binomial
      "Calculate the binomial coefficient."
      ^BigInt [^Integer n ^Integer k]
      (let [a (inc n)]
           (loop [b 1
                  c 1]
                 (if (> b k)
                   c
                   (recur (inc b) (* (/ (- a b) b) c))))))
```

**Java**

```
public class Hello {
    public static final IFn binomial;

    static {
        Clojure.var("clojure.core", "require").invoke(Clojure.read("sample.hello"));
        binomial = Clojure.var("sample.hello", "binomial");
    }

    public static BigInteger binomial(int n, int k) {
        Object a = binomial.invoke(n, k);
        return ((BigInt) a).toBigInteger();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that type hints (emphasis on the work "hint") are only used in Clojure for compiler optimizations, and cannot coerce types (or even warn if the wrong type is present!).  I would never use them unless you have profiled with [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) etc.

Having said that, I would tweak Martin's answer just a bit:

```
(defn binomial
  "Calculate the binomial coefficient."
  [n k]
  (biginteger
    (let [a (inc n)]
      (loop [b 1
             c 1]
        (if (> b k)
          c
          (recur (inc b) (* (/ (- a b) b) c)))))))
```

This emphasizes that the result of the `let` block will always be coerced to `BigInteger`.  Also, it removes the deceptive "casting" to type `Integer` at the beginning.

If you are really worried a user may provide non-integer arguments, use an `assert` or similar as the first line of the function:

```
(assert (and (int? n) (int? k))) ; or `integer?` or `pos-int?`
```

It is also often helpful to coerce input args to a known type, which can bypass the combinatorical explosion of "maybes"

```
(defn binomial
  "Calculate the binomial coefficient."
  [n k]
  (assert (and (pos-int? n) (pos-int? k))) 
  (let [n (biginteger n)
        k (biginteger k)
        a (inc n)]
    (loop [b 1
           c 1]
      (if (> b k)
        c
        (recur (inc b) (* (/ (- a b) b) c))))))
```

In this case, the coercion of the return type is unnecessary, since math operations on `BigInteger`
values will always produce another `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the function [`biginteger`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/biginteger) to force Clojure to return `java.math.BigInteger` (and avoid converting in Java):

```
(defn binomial
  "Calculate the binomial coefficient."
  [^Integer n ^Integer k]
  (let [a (inc n)]
    (loop [b 1
           c 1]
      (if (> b k)
        (biginteger c)
        (recur (inc b) (* (/ (- a b) b) c))))))
```

Tests:

```
(class (binomial 5 3))
=> java.math.BigInteger
(class (binomial 20 10))
=> java.math.BigInteger
```